# Xamarin support for AdMob Rewarded Interstitial

Tags: xamarin, admob, xamarin.android, interstitial

Today I noticed AdMob is offering rewarded interstitial option. I'd like to integrate it in my game. Does the current Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads support the integration?

Has anyone tried it? Love to hear from your experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have just attempted to integrate them and they work fine for me in debug (yet to try in release mode - will update once I've tried it)

Simply create an interstitial ad as you normally would but use the Reward Video ad unit ID instead of the usual interstitial ad ID.

If you want to try it yourself, the sample Reward Video ad unit ID provided by Google for testing is: 
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

Answer (score 0):

```
#region RewardedViewAd
        private IRewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;
        private void InitialRewardVideo()
        {
            rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.GetRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
            rewardedVideoAd.RewardedVideoAdListener = this;
            this.LoadRewardAd();
        }
        private void LoadRewardAd()
        {
            if (!rewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded)
            {
#if DEBUG
                rewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(" ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
#else
                rewardedVideoAd.LoadAd("ca-app-pub-9045308343519031/327467645", new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
#endif
            }
        }
        private void StartRewardedVideoAd()
        {
            if (rewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded)
            {
                rewardedVideoAd.Show();
            }
        }
        public void OnRewarded(IRewardItem reward)
        {
            var coins = reward.Amount;
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdClosed()
        {
            this.LoadRewardAd();
        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
        {

        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
        {

        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
        {

        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoAdOpened()
        {

        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoCompleted()
        {

        }

        public void OnRewardedVideoStarted()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            this.rewardedVideoAd.Pause(this);
            base.OnPause();
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            this.rewardedVideoAd.Resume(this);
            base.OnResume();
        }
        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            this.rewardedVideoAd.Destroy(this);
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
        #endregion;
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you are going in your answer? This will help future people who view this answer be able to implement it themselves. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)